# Jquery hiding images with parent class

Tags: jquery, image, hide

Consider this HTML:

```
<span class="leagueTogglehome">
 <img src="/images/formLeagueAll.png" id="Up" class="homeLeagueSwitch" />
 <img src="/images/formLeague.png" id="Down" class="homeLeagueSwitch" />
</span>
```

I want to hide one of the two buttons using Jquery:

```
$('span.leagueTogglehome img#Up').hide();
$('span.leagueTogglehome img#Down').hide();
```

What actually happens is that two other images with the 'Up' and 'Down' id's are hidden instead. They are in a container of a different class, so why are they hidden and not the two I intend to hide. I have even included the class of the parent contain for the button sI want to hide.

This makes no sense does it?

The 'other' img tag:

```
<span class="toggle" id="home">
 <img src="/images/formHomeUp.png" id="Up" class="homeToggleResults"/>
 <img src="/images/formHomeOverallUp.png" id="Down" class="homeToggleResults"/>
</span>
```

Comment: What does the "other" `<img>` tags look like, could you post the rest of your HTML or a jsFiddle?

Comment: You cannot have same id in different elements, you should have a class also for up & down

Comment: @Karl-Anderson I have added the 'other' mg tag details to the original post

Answer (score 1):

According to w3, `id` is [supposed to be unique per html page](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)'s what jquery itself says about selecting with an id:

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

So I'm guessing the "other img tag" appears in the dom before the one you're attempting to modify?

Comment: Yes it appears before the image I want to hide. I thought if you gae the element a parent with a unique div you could then keep then qualify which element ID to use?

Comment: @user2056238 Substitute "class" for your word "ID", and you'd be completely true.  :-)  IDs, however, must be completely unique - one id goes to exactly one element.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing was/is possible it was an error on my part, I'm tired and was referencing the wrong parent DIV. I wasn't aware that for valdi amrk-up all IDs on the page must be unique. I thought it was valid/necessary only to make them unique WITHIN a parent.